Setting Launch Config for Python Project
I have a python project thats basically a module and I have a test file test/mytest.py (VS Code Version: 1.92.2 (Universal))
Update: I found out that apparently the Python plugin might not have been selected although installed. And therefore there was no .vscode/launch.json file to navigate to. This appears to be the problem. I would say that VSCode documentation need to be clear about this.
To be clear for a beginner the following are NOT clear:

Do you need the plugin to do debugging have a .vscode/launch.json

Whether launch.json applies to only debugging.

How you could have more than one launch.config

That the launch.json applies at the project level or workspace level.
import unittest
from src.my_database import MyDatabase


but I am getting errors when I try to debug this.  It only works if I do -m unnitest mytest.py but if I run/debug the module there is no history of this choice to run as module, and I need to keep re-entering it. Amazingly in era of AI VSCode does not have the least suggestion about where to set a launch config json file.
I was expecting it to at least save my last debug module command. And I was expecting the help of VSCode to show me where to set a launch config. Perhaps there is some setting for memory of commands that I turned off?
structure is:
  main.py

  src/my_database.py

  test/my_test.py

I am open to suggestions about whether I should reference using src. like I am. I also have a config.json ready to go but I dont know how to set it and associate it with this project.
VS documentation says: "However, for most debugging scenarios, creating a launch configuration file is beneficial because it allows you to configure and save debugging setup details. VS Code keeps debugging configuration information in a launch.json file located in a .vscode folder in your workspace (project root folder) or in your user settings or workspace settings.
To create a launch.json file, select create a launch.json file in the Run start view."  but I dont get to this screen at all. Instead I see the Variables, Watch, Callstack, Breakpoints etc when I click on Arrow/Gear icon on left hand panel. Documentation indicates I can set it but what I actually see when I click that left hand side button is.
I am not seeing this screen at all no matter what I try:

{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Unittest)",
            ...
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
            }
        }
    ]
}


Hello, this may be because the launch.json file is already configured. You can click on the settings button in the upper right corner to enter the launch.json to add a new setting. Or try restarting vscode and creating a new workspace to see if that works.

follow the Python Debug Tutorial in a new clean workspace to get to know how it works, then apply it to your current workspace

I was able to access after locating the microsoft python extension and clicking on it. before that I tried cd .vscode and there was no such directory for some reason but afterwards I did see the directory and launch.json

Yes, I will try the debug tutorial. the problem I am having now which is different is that having applied the new lauch config I still cannot import from src directory the module it does not find it.

You could create a .env file under your workspace.
Add the PYTHONPATH of your src like this:
PYTHONPATH=PATH/TO/src

Then add the following line to your settings.json:
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"

